# How to make font match in ggplot between geom_text and stat_cor?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I have made a linear regression figure in R and would like to place some of the statistical output inside of the figure. The `stat_cor` function allows me to add the R2 and p-value however it does not allow you to add the slope or slope error. I can add the latter two using `geom_text` however the font is different between `stat_cor` and `geom_text`. In my opinion, the `stat_cor` font looks cleaner, so how can I get the `geom_text` to look like the `stat_cor` font?

Example Dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

beer <- read.csv("http://users.stat.umn.edu/~helwig/notes/MNbeer.csv")

ggplot(data = beer, aes(x = ABV, y = IBU)) +
  stat_smooth(method = 'lm') +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14, color = 'black')) +
  stat_cor(aes(label = paste(..rr.label.., ..p.label.., sep = "~`,`~")),
           label.x = 4, size = 4)
```

Here is where I get the slope and its standard error

```
model <- lm(IBU~ABV, data = beer)
summary(model)
```

I add the slope ± SE to the plot below using `geom_text` however their is a difference in the font between the `stat_cor` output and the `geom_text` output.

```
ggplot(data = beer, aes(x = ABV, y = IBU)) +
  stat_smooth(method = 'lm') +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(x = 4.45 , y = 88,
            label = 'Slope = 19.79 ± 2.67',
            size = 4.5) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14, color = 'black')) +
  stat_cor(aes(label = paste(..rr.label.., ..p.label.., sep = "~`,`~")),
           label.x = 4, size = 4)
```

The ideal figure would have the R2, p-value, and slope ± SE all in the same font as `stat_cor`.

Comment: The font is the same. The issue is that you plot your label multiple times which gives the "unclean" look. Try with `annotate("text", x = 4.45, ...)` instead of `geom_text` to add the label only once.

Comment: That did the trick! Just for other's in case they run into the same issue:`annotate("text", x = 4.45 , y = 88, size = 4.5, label = 'Slope = 19.79 ± 2.67')`